# Why does this result in 0 and upsidedown not?

Tags: c#, math

Currently I am writing my thesis and I was confronted with a behavior of .Net C# that I had never seen before. I am talking about an error in a calculation.
I implemented this formula:

1/2 * (Theta i-1 + Theta i) + Sum(Alph k, k=1, i-1)

This formula is applied to 4 objects. Theta is in all objects declared as float with the value 1,5708. Alpha is initialized with 0 and will be increased by each iteration.

**First implmentation**

```
    float alpha = 0;
    float value = 0;
    for (int sphereCount = 1; sphereCount < this.spheres.Count; sphereCount++)
    {
        value = (1/2) * (this.spheres[sphereCount - 1].Theta + this.spheres[sphereCount].Theta);
        alpha += value;
    }
```

With this version value is always 0.0!
So I changed it to:

**Working implementaion**

```
    float alpha = 0;
    float value = 0;
    for (int sphereCount = 1; sphereCount < this.spheres.Count; sphereCount++)
    {
        value =(this.spheres[sphereCount - 1].Theta + this.spheres[sphereCount].Theta) * 1/2;
        alpha += value;
    }
```

By removing the brackets around the 1/2 and placing it at the end of the calculation it worked.

WHY IS THAT SO???

It seems when you place 1/2 in brackets not depending on the position of 1/2 the result is 0.0. But also when i place (1/2) at the end it results in 0.0.
Does anyone here have an idea why?

Comment: How do you know it is 0.0?  I suspect this is a floating point question.  Try `Console.Out.WriteLine(value);`

Comment: Not relevant to the question but: you're not including the last sphere either way, is that intentional?

Comment: @ChrisShain: Used the Debugger ;-) No need for console output.

Comment: @harold: I am ignoring the first sphere cause i already calulated that on its own ;-)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using `float`s rather than `double`s ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This

```
(1 / 2)
```

evaluates to 0 because it's integer division. If you say

```
(1 / 2f)
```

or

```
(1 / (float) 2)
```

you'll be fine because it forces float divsion. Or, even better, just write `0.5`.

Comment: Oh man NOOO... I thought that c# is so smart to convert the 1/2 into a float... BTW Using (1/2.0) results in a double so you need to cast the whole result into a float.

Comment: @Christoph the calculation will most likely be performed on double values and then truncated to float at the end.  Also, C# certainly won't convert the `1 / 2` calculation to float when you've specifically isolated it from the float operator by enclosing it in parentheses.

Comment: @Christoph: Smart? No, what if you want integer divsion? How are you going to achieve that if the compiler is guessing for you that you actually wanted `float`. That's why it doesn't do it for you. Also, if you want float just use `2f`.

Comment: You can also just append `f`: `(1/2f)`

Comment: @Christoph you can do `2.0f` if you don't want to cast, this makes a 2.0 float literal.

Comment: But do you have any idea why the 1/2 works at the end of the calculation? That's what bothers me

Comment: @Christoph it's because it does `x * 1` then `/ 2`, where x is a floating point type, the operation gets casted to a float/double, then it divides that by integer 2, which still results in a floating point number.  `double * float => double`, `float * int => float`, `double * int => double`.

Comment: @Christoph because the calc is performed left to right.  Without the parentheses, you have (floatexpression) * 1 so 1 is implicitly converted; then you have (floatexpression) / 2, so 2 is implicitly converted.

Comment: @Christoph: Because the numerator will evaluate as expression of type `float` and then you're in the realm of floating division when you divide by 2.

Comment: @Jason: Correct me when I am wrong, what btw might now be so. Doesn't c# recognizes when I use an float or double value in a calculation that all other values are treated as float/double and the result also is a float/double?

Comment: @Christoph: No, it does not do that. You have an expression `(1 / 2)`.  The compiler needs to know which `/` to invoke. It sees that both operands are `Int32`, so it uses `/(Int32, Int32)`. It doesn't matter if the result of this expression is being multiplied by a `float` or not.

Answer (score 3):

If you write 1/2 the result is calculated using integer division that gives an integer result. You can force a floating point division by changing one of the numbers to a floating point number, as in `1/2f`.

Or you could just write `0.5` which IMHO is more readable than 1/2.

Comment: Or you could write `/ 2` which is also more readable than `* 1 / 2`

Answer (score 1):

Why multiply by `1`?  Rather than this:

```
value =(this.spheres[sphereCount - 1].Theta + this.spheres[sphereCount].Theta) * 1/2;
```

why not write this:

```
value =(this.spheres[sphereCount - 1].Theta + this.spheres[sphereCount].Theta) / 2;
```

Comment: If we're simplifying the formula, and "Theta is in all objects declared as float with the value 1,5708", then the whole algorithm could be `alpha = this.spheres[0].Theta * this.spheres.Count;`

Comment: @Jay +1 for that; I didn't read any deeper than necessary to address the immediate question.

Answer (score 0):

You should write 1.0/2 or 0.5 instead 1/2.

1/2 is an integer division which results in an integer 0.

Answer (score 0):

Because 1/2 is treated as integer arithmetic and as such is rounded to 0.

Removing the parenthesis changes the order of operations, and now you are dividing your whole (floating point) formula by two and arriving at a floating point answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `1` and `2` are integer values, not floating point values.

When you divide the integer value `1` by the integer value `2`, the result is the integer value `0`, not the floating point value `0.5`.

When you remove the parentheses and change the order of the multiplication, the other part of the expression will first be multiplied by `1`, which will implicitly convert the integer value `1` into a floating point value. Then the result is divided by `2`, which will also be implicitly converted into a floating point value.

So what you end up doing is:

```
value = ( (this.spheres[sphereCount - 1].Theta + this.spheres[sphereCount].Theta) * (float)1 ) / (float)2;
```